# Sort a list of file names numerically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, numeric

I am making a program that shows pictures that were downloaded automatically by said program. I have it so the program makes a list of all the pictures as PIL.Image objects.
The pictures are saved as jpegs and they are named numerically (1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg.....).
The problem I am having is that when I try to make said list I need to get all the paths to all the images to make the PIL.Image objects.
I used os.listdir(path) and it worked great until I realised that it did not "sort" the images numerical.
That means that it went like this: [1.jpg,10.jpg,100.jpg,101.jpg......2.jpg,20.jpg....]
I need a way to sort this list so it outputs: [1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg.....]
I can't sort like I would integers because they are strings with the ".jpg" at the end.
A simplified version of my problem:

```
for i in os.listdir(path):
    ...
output: ["1.jpg","10.jpg","100.jpg", ...]

I want something to output: ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg",....]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do :

```
nums = sorted([ int(num.split('.')[0]) for num in output]) #split the names and sort numbers
final_output = [ str(i)+".jpg" for i in nums] #append file extension and create another list.
```

---

One liner :

```
final_output = [ str(i)+".jpg" for i in sorted([ int(num.split('.')[0]) for num in output])]
```

---

Note: While this may not be optimal, but gets the thing done.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the output of listdir based on names in the following way,

```py
import os
for i in sorted(os.listdir(".."), key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0])):
    print(i)
```

Here the os.listdir output is split by '.' and then converted it to int before sorting them.